# config parameter 'class' for python logging configuration through a config file, is causing an ImportError

Tags: python, logging

Im trying to configure logging for my project by extending the TimedRotatingFileHandler class and using a configfile to configure the logging.
The configfile is important because i want to be able to configure my logging that way, however i run into an Import error and dont know how to make the classname be reachable from my configfile..

The error i get is ..

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\config.py", line 160, in _install_handlers
    klass = _resolve(klass)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\config.py", line 101, in _resolve
    __import__(used)
ImportError: No module named rtlogHandler
```

project/cfg/log_config.ini

```
[handler_fileHandler]
class=common.rtlogHandler.rtLogFileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=logFormatter
args=('rtCompute', 'h', 1, 5)
```

my logging class in 
project/src/common/rtlogHandler.py

```
import logging
import datetime

# (filename, when='h', interval=1, backupCount=100, encoding=None, delay=False, utc=False)
class rtLogFileHandler(logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    '''
    Extended to accommodate for current date and custom path for log file name
    '''
    def __init__(self, file_name, rotate_type, rotate_interval, no_of_backup):
        #   use timestamp in filename
        today = datetime.date.today()
        file_name = file_name + '_' + today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        super(rtLogFileHandler, self).__init__(file_name, rotate_type, rotate_interval, no_of_backup)
    def print_me(self):
        print "print me from log file handler "
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Has you `__init__.py` in `project/src/common`?
2. Has you `project/src/common` in path?
   You can check it by: `print(sys.path)`
   You can use `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.